# How to properly implement this polymorphic relationship in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to build an inventory for users in Laravel 5.8, however the items have their own properties, therefore I needed to set up a polymorphic relationship. When attaching items to users, it tries to add the model User to the table on `itemable_type` and the user's ID to `itemable_id` aswell as add the User's ID to `user_id`, something I could workaround by passing the models I need, but when I try to retrieve them it tries to find item with itemable_type = 'App\Models\User', which makes me think something's completely wrong here. Can I have some orientation on how to solve it?

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function inventory()
    {
        return $this->morhpToMany(InventoryItem::class, 'itemable', 'user_inventories', null, 'itemable_id')
            ->withPivot('amount', 'notes');
    }
}
```

```php
class InventoryItem extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'character_inventories';

    protected $fillable = [
        'character_id', 'itemable_type', 'amount', 'parent_id', 'notes'
    ];

    public function cloth()
    {
        return $this->mophedByMany(Cloth::class, 'itemable');
    }

    public function food()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Food::class, 'itemable');
    }

    // Other similar relations
}
```

```php
// The Inventory migration:
 Schema::create('user_inventories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('itemable_id');
    $table->string('itemable_type');
    $table->unsignedInteger('amount')->default(0);
    $table->text('notes', 65535)->nullable();

    $table->foreign('character_id')->references('id')->on('characters');
});
```

The expected result is the User model to have different items in his inventory, but the relation is trying to query by joinning to itself and filtering by user type instead of actual items.

The error:

```sql
Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'user_inventories' (SQL: 
select `user_inventories`.*, 
    `user_inventories`.`itemable_id` as `pivot_itemable_id`, 
    `user_inventories`.`itemable_type` as `pivot_itemable_type`, 
    `user_inventories`.`amount` as `pivot_amount`, 
    `user_inventories`.`parent_id` as `pivot_parent_id`, 
    `user_inventories`.`notes` as `pivot_notes` 
from `user_inventories` 
inner join `user_inventories` on `user_inventories`.`id` = `user_inventories`.`itemable_id` 
where `user_inventories`.`itemable_id` in (4) 
and `user_inventories`.`itemable_type` = App\Models\User)
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly suspect that you have to references the user table in the `inventory` relation. In general it is a million times easier just following the `Laravel` convention for naming.

```
public function inventory()
{
    return $this->morhpToMany(InventoryItem::class, 'itemable', 'users', null, 'itemable_id')
        ->withPivot('amount', 'notes');
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. As long as I know, thar third argument refers to the table where the relation happens (the pivot table). Still, I gave it a try, and exactly, now it tries to find all the fields (itemable_id, itemable_type, etc) in the `users` table. The problem is that when I do `$user->inventory()->attach($inventoryItem)` it adds the model User to the `itemable_type` field, and same when I try to retrieve the user's inventory